# Tuple assignment order

Tags: python, python-internals, order-of-execution

Let's take the following fibonacci generator:

```
def fib():
    previous = 0
    current = 1
    tmp = None
    while True:
        tmp = current + previous
        previous = current
        current = tmp
        print (current)
        input('...')
```

I am using `tmp` as a way to stash the current value before assigning the next. Another way to do this would be with tuple assignment where I don't even need a `tmp`:

```
def fib():
    previous = 0
    current = 1
    while True:
        current, previous = current+previous, current
        print (current)
        input('...')
```

I'm wondering if someone could explain the 'order' in which the tuple assignment is evaluated. Does everything on the right-hand side get evaluated first? (It would seem that way) or are individual terms bound and assigned 'together' in a certain way (for example, first assign `current=current+previous`; then `previous=current`). It would seem the former approach is the way its working but I'm wondering if someone could definitively explain how it works, and perhaps point to the place in the Language docs where that's done (or even the C code if that is done in a single place).

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't find this before but here you go: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment-stmt

Comment: @mkrieger1 that right there is more useful than the linked duplicate, which doesn't given any references. Thank you.